# Is Gas used on Ropsten Indicative of Gas used on Mainnet

Tags: gas, gas-estimate

I have developed a simple Smart Contract, which uses several Upgradeable Contracts from OpenZeppelin. I have deployed it to the Ropsten Network. It cost me a total of 11476134 in gas. Is the amount reported by the Ropsten deployment indicative of what I will need to pay  to deploy to the Mainnet? At this amount of gas, I would need to pay 1.41ETH x 4200$US = 5922$US (11476134 x 120/gwei = 1411564482/1000000000 = 1.41ETH).

Thank you. J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the amount of gas used should be exactly the same, if the code is the same.

Note that you need to be careful with possible dependencies to other contracts: the mainnet may have different codes for your dependencies, so the gas usage may be different that way.

The actual gas prices (fees) are of course very different.